# Android application update

Tags: android

i have an app in the android market that utilizes the database as well as the shared preference .I need to update my application to add more functionality and new tables

I have updated the database portion in the upgrade() method of the helper class.

Please help in explaining the process of android application update.what happens behind the scene.How is application updated after we submit the updated apk in market

What all more thing need to be taken care apart from database

Please help it is urgent

Answer (score 3):

During Google IO 2012 about 2 Weeks ago they presented a new way of updating the Android Apk from the Play store. So basically you just download everything whats new and add it to the apk which is already available. So now it will take upto 70% less data for upgrading an apk. So Your database will be updated. Just the new data will be downloaded and will be added to the app. The shared prefrences dont get deleted, they stay saved even after an update. I hope I could help.